# Entity Framework 7 commands clarification - migrations add vs. database update?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I'm working on an ASP.NET 5 app that uses Entity Framework 7 with migrations to alter the application's Microsoft Sql Server database.

I'm running into a few issues when I reach the migrations step, and I would like clarification on what the Entity Framework commands `migrations add` and `database update` do.

It's my understanding that

`> dnx ef migrations add Initial`

creates a C# file ending in the name *Initial* in a folder named *Migrations* containing code that will create tables based on the application model classes, and

`> dnx ef database update`

executes the code that will add those changes to the database. However, after the `migrations add` command, the database has already been created, and the console gives an error when I run the `database update` command, saying that the tables already exist.

From what I've read on different tutorials, it seems like `migrations add` shouldn't actually affect the database, and the changes would take place when you run `database update`, but it doesn't look like that's the case.

Can someone explain what each of these steps are doing and how they fit together? Thanks in advance!

Comment: ef migration add Initial don't create a database, just the migration file. I suspect you created a database before and run update on it, then you delete the migration file and recreated it without deleting the database before

Comment: I had these issues when I created models on an existing database. I just manually added the name of the migration onto the __efhistory table. Whilst EF7 is focusing on code first, the reality is that many development processes are database first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dnx ef migrations add` shouldn't create the database. I suspect `DbContext.Database.EnsureCreated()` is being called somewhere in your application code giving it this effect.

Comment: I had this line in my `DbContext` class. I've removed it and the commands work like they should. Thanks!